# 4 moderate severity vulnerabilities Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am trying to fix these issues on my VUE CLI installation
Will anyone know how?

```
Will install @vue/cli-service@4.1.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/ssri
  @vue/cli-service  4.0.0-alpha.0 - 4.5.12
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ssri
  Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
  node_modules/@vue/cli-service
  cacache  10.0.4 - 11.0.0 || 13.0.0 - 14.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ssri
  node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/cacache
    terser-webpack-plugin  2.1.1 - 2.3.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cacache
    node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
```

Comment: What command were you running beforehand?

Comment: I only put in the nerminal  npm install